# How configure to read all user accessible applications via SAML authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, config, saml-2.0

Created some user groups and assigned users to each group based on user role. I have 'X' - Number of applications, All were configured in Azure AD. Now each application assigned to one or multiple groups. Now created one Portal(SP - Service provider) to display what are all the applications user can access. Using SAML Authentication SP initiate request IDP. On Successful Automatization IDP send SAML token. Token contains some data. How to configure enterprise Application (SAML - IDP) to retrieve user accessible applications list.

I am able to create application in IDP and also Ii am able to retrieve SAML token
I need to config to retrieve user accessible applications list.

Answer (score 1):

->display what are all the applications user can access

we could use graph api to [list appRoleAssignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) along with users.

```
/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/appRoleAssignments
```

or query users along with appRoleAssignments using `expand` parameter:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$expand=appRoleAssignments
```

If you are trying to list all users with their roles, then we need this api which requires a token generated by client credential flow.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$expand=appRoleAssignments
```

[image]

Comment: Tiny Wang - Thanks for your response. 
But My question is different. I cannot  use graph API. only SAML through I need to retrieve application data from Azure AD

Comment: per my understanding, I'm not sure whether SAML provides this ability for list user application role... let's wait someone one else to share their ideas on it..